# Can't format my calculations with number_format

Tags: php

I have these values:

```
value x: 0.0399
value y: 8400
total = (float)valuex * valuey;

// formatted number;

total =(total,2);
```

```
EDIT:

$durata_contractului = get_field('durata_contractului',$post->ID); // 60
$avans_produs = get_field('avans_produs', $post->ID); // 1500
$pret_total = get_field('pret_total', $post->ID); // 10000
$dobanda = get_field('dobanda_oferta', $post->ID); // 3.99
$valoarea_reziduala_oferta = get_field('valoare_reziduala_oferta', $post->ID); // 100
$avans_float = ($pret_total * $avans_produs) / 100; 

$val_rez_float = ($pret_total * $valoarea_reziduala_oferta) / 100; 

$dobanda_oficiala = ($dobanda / 100); 
                                    
$valoarea_finantata = $pret_total - $avans_float - $val_rez_float;                                    

$durata_in_ani = $durata_contractului / 12;

$dobanda_anuala_pf = ((float)$dobanda * $valoarea_finantata);

$dobanda_anuala_pf = number_format($dobanda_anuala_pf, 2);
```

The last variable formatted is: 33.516 instead of 335.16 which is the real value from the calculator..

How can I format the correct way and show the comma after hundred ?

Comment: Please provide that actual PHP code you are using

Comment: I have modified my code.. Thanks

Comment: (1) See this [link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a7da8567c861016dbb41dedf737b82c7a7c8ece6)  ---  Please click "Execute code" and see what happens (2) For your case, please see this [link2](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0076baabe19836e5abaa245129ae59b73834cddc)

Comment: thank you , I finnaly figured out.. I used the non-transformed value , and thats why it didnt calculated correctly; Sorry for making a mess!